# What does Free and Allocated memory mean in Android Monitor?

Tags: android, performance

I am using Android Studio to profile my app. Under Android Monitor->Memory tab, I see Free (9MB) and Allocated (15 MB) memory for my app. What does this mean? Per my understanding, when zygote starts an app, it allocates a pre-defined memory chunk to your app. So for my app, it might have allocated 24 MB and currently my app is using 15 MB. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

Dark blue: Amount of memory that your app is currently using.
Light blue: Available, unallocated memory.

https://developer.android.com/tools/performance/memory-monitor/index.html

Comment: So for my app, it might have allocated 24 MB and currently my app is using 15 MB. Is my understanding correct?    -   Exactly

Comment: How did Android OS figure out that my app needs 24 MB?